# Real-Time plot embedded in Tkinter Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Could you help me to embed a real-time plot to my Tkinter GUI ? I have tried a lot of examples but nothing works for my Tkinter Class.

> I have defined a GUI Class and initialize method()

---

```
class Gui():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.initialize()
```

> Next, I have embedded plot into a GUI but it does not work properly

```
def initialize(self):

        self.entry = tk.Entry(root)

        f = plt.figure()
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        axes = f.add_subplot(111)
        line, = axes.plot([], [], ':ko')
        axes.set_autoscaley_on(True)
        axes.grid()
        xdata = []
        ydata = []
```

> and then:

```
for ind in range(0,100):
            ydata.append(ind)
            xdata.append(sin(2*pi*ind))
            line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
            axes.relim()
            axes.autoscale_view()
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=frame)
            canvas.show()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
            canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
            time.sleep(1)
```

> and finally, I have show canvas in the frame but don't work.

```
frame = Frame(self.root)
frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

Button1=Button(frame,text="Draw")
Button1.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill= Y )

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=frame)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? You provide code but you don't say what the expected results are (we can sometimes infer those), nor do you say what it _is_ doing.

Comment: The main problem lies in the fact that the plot will be not automatically updated. I saw only one point on the plot. I would like that my plot shows the values in real-time over the program runs!